# Universal Windows App cannot set slider value

Tags: c#, slider, settings, win-universal-app, roaming

> SOLVED
>
> Actually, I solved the problem by removing the "Value_Changed" event from the XAML and adding it manually with C# AFTER setting the value of the slider. Otherwise it looks like the slider take the minimum value possible - Thanks to all

I have two page, one page have a slider which have to takes the value of a variable from the first page.

Main.xaml.cs

```
public static int val;
...//Some stuff here

val = Converti.ToInt32(roamingSetting.Value["Setting"]);
...//Some stuff there
```

Then the second page

Second.xaml.cs

```
public Settings()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    slider.Value = Main.val;    //looks like this line does not do his job  
}
private void slider_ValueChanged(object s, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    writeToRoaming(slider.Value.Tostring());
}
```

Slider XAML

```
<Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="5" Maximum="100" IsThumbToolTipEnabled="True" ValueChanged="slider_ValueChanged"/>
```

The fact is that the value of the slider is never set to the value of the setting

Comment: what's the problem here, can you rephrase?

Comment: Are you settings slider value before in the roaming settings?

Comment: The setting value has a default value which exist

Comment: can you post your slider xaml?

Comment: Done
In fact, it looks like "val" is changed by slider_valuchanged() Event

Comment: why are you reading roaming settings in mainpage, we can do the same in settings constructor

Comment: Well, actually, I moved the roaming settings read in another class, but it doesn't change anything I think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93919/discussion-between-haseeb-asif-and-sven-borden).

Comment: @HaseebAsif Thanks for your support, I was finally able to fix this, gonna push a edit tomorrow to explains

Answer (score 0):

It might be some issue with biding of slider with your val variable. But we you can get the new value from events args in slide value change event. It will write the latest values into the roaming settings and fix the problem.

```
private void slider_ValueChanged(object s, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    writeToRoaming(e.NewValue.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated your scenario and it works for me but think you could be seeing one of the following:

- there is no roaming settings value
- the roaming settings value that is being used is outside the maximum and minimum values that you've defined for the slider

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve it by changing the declaration of the event function